# Correct code matching

Tags: r, lambda, match, transform, time-series

I am performing a box-cox test and obtaining the lambda value. I then wanted to round this to 5d.p and set it so that if:

λ < 0.25 the transformation would be set as log

0.25 ≤ λ < 0.75 the transformation would be set to sqrt

0.75 ≤ λ there will be no transformation

here is the code that i had written:

```
Data.col<-c(5403.676,6773.505, 7231.117, 7835.552, 5236.710, 5526.619, 6555.782,11464.727, 7210.069, 7501.610, 8670.903,10872.935, 8209.023, 8153.393,10196.448,13244.502, 8356.733,10188.442,10601.322,12617.821, 11786.526,10044.987,11006.005,15101.946,10992.273,11421.189,10731.312)
transform.method <- format(round(BoxCox.lambda(Data.col, method = "loglik"), 5),nsmall=5)

log.values <- seq(0, 0.24999, by = 0.00001)
sqrt.values <- seq(0.25, 0.74999, by = 0.00001)

which.transform.log <- transform.method %in% log.values
which.transform.sqrt <- transform.method %in% sqrt.values

if (which.transform.log == "TRUE"){
  as.log <- "log"
  Data.new <- log(Data.col)
} else {
  if (which.transform.sqrt == "TRUE"){
    as.log <- "sqrt"
    Data.new <- sqrt(Data.col)
  } else {
    as.log <- "no"
    Data.new <- Data.col
  }
}
```

However the lambda is saying that it is 0.60000 but which.transform is outputting "FALSE" saying that there isnt a match in sqrt.values

can you see what is going wrong, and also if there is an easier way of doing this?

Edit:
I have tried setting transform.method to 0.1 and it results in TRUE as a match in log.values...so i dont understand why it isnt working for 0.6

thankyou :)

Answer (score 1):

what about something like:

```
trans<- round(BoxCox.lambda(Data.col, method = "loglik"),5)
categ<-as.character( c(cut(trans,c(0,0.25,0.75,Inf),right=FALSE)) )
Data.new<-switch(categ,
    "1"=log(Data.col),
    "2"=sqrt(Data.col),
    "3"=Data.col
)
```

Then you can easily expand with more transformations. Feel free to remove the rounding.

And if you want to inspect which transformation you can always use:

```
c("log","sqrt","non")[as.numeric(categ)]
```

Regarding your code, you need to format the sequences as well, eg:

```
log.values <- format( seq(0, 0.24999, by = 0.00001),nsmall=5)
sqrt.values <- format(seq(0.25, 0.74999, by = 0.00001),nsmall=5)
```

But I would strongly recommend you to do it in a way like the one I suggested instead.